# What control to use for display a row from Database

Tags: asp.net

I have something like this

```
select  sum(value) from database.table
```

And this will display only one number for example : 6546.00
What is the best control that i should use to display the selected data to my .aspx page
I don't want use DatagridView .
I think : `label , textbox(onlyRead) , ListVIew` or something else ?

Comment: If you are never going to have more than one row then just use a label.

Answer (score 2):

- If you **just want to show** the info then just use `Label`
- If you want to **Edit and Update** the Info then just use `Text

  box`..
- If you have **more than one info** to show then just use `Listview`..

*choice depends on your need..*

But for displaying single value on screen then `Label` is best